# Need to animate an object to top and make it go back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need my plane to fly up the runway (which is the map) and come back on click. So far it only goes up.
    Anything java script/html/ jquery related. simple suggestions please. ty ^^
    Here's my current code::

```
<div class="Map"><div id="MovingPlane1"></div></div>
```

JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#MovingPlane1").click(function(){
            $("#MovingPlane1").animate({bottom:"250px"},"slow");
        });
    });
<script>
```

Comment: I have one image and would like it to animate to top and come back without giving a second image. Is there a way to make it rotate and come back? perhaps something with coordinates or is that a little too complicated?

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/aqigiy/edit#javascript,html,live)*

Give both your planes a class `.plane` and use this code:

```
$(".plane").click(function(){
      
   $(this).animate({bottom:250},800,function(){
       $(this).animate({bottom:0},800);
   });
  
});
```

Inside the animation callback you *redo* the initial position.

Comment: ah so i have to create two different images and divs, then give it that function? if it's two different images how do i hide the second one before the animation starts? (sorry im quite nube :P)

Comment: @needhelp - Before the click action you can say that element to hide! : `$('#MovingPlane2').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(this).animate({bottom:"250px"},"slow",function(){
   $(this).animate({bottom:"0px"},"slow");
});
```

Comment: Would be worth replacing the second selector with $(this).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the plane to come back on the second click use the following:

```
var plane1up = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#MovingPlane1").click(function(){
        $("#MovingPlane1").animate({bottom:(plane1up==true ? "0px" : "250px")},"slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: i would like it to move back and forward only in one click, is that possible?

Comment: Then use one of the two other solutions. They do exactly that by moving the plane back in the callback function, so when the first animation is complete.